# Comprobar que el valor de un input type number sea más grande que 0

Tags: jquery

Necesito comprobar que el número introducido en un `input` es más grande que 0.

Tengo un formulario de este estilo, con esta función de jquery:

```js
$("#cantidad").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() <= 0){
   $("#guardar").attr("disabled",true);
  } else {
            $("#guardar").attr("disabled",false);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number" id="cantidad"/>
  <button type="submit" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Al poner el número con el teclado, esta función funciona correctamente pero si pongo el número con el ratón utilizando las flechas que aparecen en los inputs de tipo numérico no me lo cambia. Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Porqué no usas jquery Validation? , la forma como lo estas haciendo es muy poco práctica y es molesta para el usuario final.

Comment: No entiendo porque usas `<= (menor igual a)` si dices en tu pregunta "Necesito comprobar que el número introducido en un input es más grande que 0."

Comment: Por que si el número es menor o igual a 0 el botón de guardar tiene que estar desactivado.

Comment: @PavloB. ya entendí, disculpa :c por eso borré mi respuesta, pero que bueno que ya alguien pudo solucionarte el problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de usar el evento `keyup`, puedes usa el evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) (`IE9+`).

Así por ejemplo:

```js
$("#cantidad").on('input', function(){
  var cant = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  $("#guardar").attr("disabled", cant <= 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number" id="cantidad"/>
  <button type="submit" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: Podrías explocarme que hace la línea `var cant = parseInt(this.value, 10);`? que significa ese 10 ahí?

Comment: @PavloB., El número 10, es la base que se aplica a la cadena. Si este no se especifica el resultado dependera del formato de la cadena. Mas info: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt).

Answer (score 3):

Tu mismo ejemplo, pero aplicando `jquery validation`... revisalo y ve si te gustaría usarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  Validar();
});

function Validar() {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "Este campo es obligatorio.",
        remote: "Por favor, rellena este campo.",
        email: "Por favor, escribe una dirección de correo válida",
        url: "Por favor, escribe una URL válida.",
        date: "Por favor, escribe una fecha válida.",
        dateISO: "Por favor, escribe una fecha (ISO) válida.",
        number: "Por favor, escribe un número entero válido.",
        digits: "Por favor, escribe sólo dígitos.",
        creditcard: "Por favor, escribe un número de tarjeta válido.",
        equalTo: "Por favor, escribe el mismo valor de nuevo.",
        accept: "Por favor, escribe un valor con una extensión aceptada.",
        maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribas más de {0} caracteres."),
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, no escribas menos de {0} caracteres."),
        rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor entre {0} y {1} caracteres."),
        range: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor entre {0} y {1}."),
        max: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor menor o igual a {0}."),
        min: jQuery.validator.format("Por favor, escribe un valor mayor o igual a {0}.")
    });


    $("#formValidate").validate({        
        success: "valid",
        submitHandler: function () {
            //Si todo esta bien aqui va el metodo que Guarda
          alert("Todo OK")
        }
    });
}

/*
$("#cantidad").keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() <= 0){
   $("#guardar").attr("disabled",true);
  } else {
            $("#guardar").attr("disabled",false);
 });*/
```

```css
/* Form Validation */
label.error {
 padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
 color: #c93605;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(164, 44, 4, 0.20);
    -moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(164, 44, 4, 0.20);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(164, 44, 4, 0.20);
    font-size:11px;
 }

form input.error {border: 1px solid #ED7A53 !important;}
form input.valid {border: 1px solid #9FC569 !important;}

.controls label.error {
 margin-top:-20px;
}
.controls .selector label.error {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 right: 0;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <br/>    <br/>
<div class="container row">
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <form class="validate-form" method="post" action="" id="formValidate">
   
    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
      <input class="form-control col-xs-5" min="1" type="number" id="cantidad" required/>
    </div>
    <br/>    <br/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
  </form>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes realizar un *parseo* del valor de tu *input*

Quiero decir, convertir el texto *cadena* de tu *input* y convertirlo a un valor *numerico*

Usando la funcion *parseInt()*

Ademas noto que no tienes el bloque *else*, por tanto si el numero es negativo no hay nada que quite el *disabled*

```js
$("#cantidad").keyup(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).val()) <= 0){
   $("#guardar").attr("disabled",true);
  }else{
                        $("#guardar").attr("disabled",false);
                }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="number" id="cantidad"/>
  <button type="submit" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No me funciona de esta manera tampoco.

Comment: Ya lo edite, prueba de nuevo

Comment: Debes validar tambien con el _else_ para en caso que el numero sea negativo no deje bloqueado el input

Comment: Tampoco. De hecho no creo que el problema sea de las condiciones `if` or `else` sencillamente no se activa con el `keyup()`

Comment: @PavloB. He editado el ejemplo, prueba y me dices, creo que es lo que necesitas

Comment: He encontrado el problema, pero éste me lleva a otro... XD Funciona si pongo el número con el teclado pero si le doy a las flechitas para poner el número con el rato no lo hace.

Answer (score 1):

debes de enlazar el evento de las 'flechitas' del campo number.

```
$("#cantidad").keyup(function(){
   enableButton();
});

$("#cantidad").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    enableButton();           
});

function enableButton()
{
    var value = parseInt($("#cantidad").val());
    if(value <= 0){
    $("#guardar").attr("disabled",true);
  }
  else{
    $("#guardar").attr("disabled",false);
  }
}
```